# Non-orientable genus of union of graphs

Tags: graph-theory, genus

It is known that the orientable genus of union of two (disjoint) graphs is the sum of their genus. So, it is natural to ask

*What can be said about the non-orientable genus of union of two (disjoint) graphs?*

Note that upper and lower bounds are known for the non-orientable genus of $k$-amalgams of two graphs with $k\geq2$ as well as the precise value of the non-orientable genus for $k=1$.

Comment: [Stahl and Beineke](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jgt.3190010114/abstract) claim in the last paragraph of their paper: "We 
note here that Corollary 3 retains  its  validity  when the phrase blocks of 
the connected  graph is  replaced by components of the graph."  I don't see why that's true though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-orientable genus $\tilde{\rm{g}}$ is not additive: consider the union of $K_5$ and $K_7$. We have $\tilde{\rm{g}}(K_5)=1$, $\tilde{\rm{g}}(K_7)=3$ and $\tilde{\rm{g}}(K_5\cup K_7)=3$: embed $K_5$ on the projective plane, $K_7$ on the torus, and take the connected sum of these two surfaces.